# SSD card as system disc check

Tags: 14.04, ssd, disk-check

I run Ubuntu on small device that file system is located on SSD card. Suddenly I found some corrupted files. How to know my system files are not corrupted?

Comment: You can compare hash sums with a backup, assuming there is a backup.

Answer (score 0):

In the `terminal`...

`sudo debsums -s` # check the MD5 sums of installed Debian packages

See `man debsums` for more information about this command.

---

Also, you can `fsck` your Ubuntu file system and check for errors...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

---

Lastly, if you dual-boot with Windows, and you installed a Windows driver to be able to read/write to ext2/3/4 partitions, remove it ASAP, as it corrupts ext2/3/4 partitions.